# JSP + Busy Status on page load until all is loaded

Tags: jsp, struts2, busy-cursor

I'm using JSP & Struts2 for development.

When I login, I call an action, which inturn takes some time to load the data on the page.

While the data is getting loaded, I want to show a busy cursor and once the page is completely loaded, remove off that.

Also I'm using jQuery to a large extent. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you might get a better user experience by postponing the long-running action call until after your page has loaded.

To achieve that, have your JSP render a busy indicator of some sort, get the data from your action with an ajax call that runs on the page's `onload` event, and finally place the content where you'd like it. I'm sure jQuery does all of this for you very easily.

Comment: hmm, that would require some code change, let me finish the functionality and then work on this, was wondering if there was an easier way!!

Comment: @Lauri Lehtinen Can you help me with that JQuery Code . I am Having same problem

Answer (score 1):

I've used plain Struts2 (no jquery) for this scenario with the **ExecuteAndWait Interceptor**. See my [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040569/get-status-of-servlet-request-before-the-response-is-returned/3041710#3041710).

Comment: Actually in my case, the data is loaded, but the population is taking time, so was looking at a way to find to show a busy cursor until the data is populated and page is rendered.